# How can I construct IP payload packet with mbuf?

Tags: wireshark, dpdk

My requirement is create to Ethernet-IP-Payload with DPDK Mbuf. DPDK application is running on on virtual machine, the packet generation function invokes the API (attached in second image). I send the packet through DPDK interface and capture on my host system (W10).

Wireshark, can not understand the ethernet protocol as IP.Is there something wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY37L.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URBrz.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, posting your code and not images of your code makes it easier to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of things you can correct in your DPDK code.

1. Network packets are big-endian, I assume you are running the Guest OS on x86. If this is true please make sure correct the endianness.
2. DPDK API rte_pktmbuf_mtod gets you the start of packet. Please fill the ethernet header first, then move 14 bytes ie `struct rte_eth_hdr` to typecast to IP and fill the data.
3. in IP field, the checksum filed is set as 0. Please cross-check if you are enabling IP-CHECKSUM offload in port_init.
4. All fields in IP has to follow BIG endian format too.
5. There is also a port filed in mbuf. With rte_mbuf_alloc it will be 0, but for sending to another port it should be the right value.

Wireshark observations

1. Byte 13 and 14 is `0xa50`. This looks like your intended payload is overwritten
2. Byte 1 is `0x45` which clearly shows, you are writing IP header content first instead of ethernet. Please use step `2` from DPDK fixes.

Comment: Thank you !That helps a lot. I indeed run it on x86, ethernet_header should be in front of ipv4_header. And I use big-endian to assign value. Eventually it works!